# Vuejs - map/get source `index/id` of input to an element `index/id` for update

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Each set of `fn[]` and `ln[]` `<input>` row must independently update its own `<p>` element. This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samimi_it/d7eo2q6w/5/) link to show the issue as they are not independently mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `fname` and `lname` are arrays you should access them by indexes and update them, and each `@input` event handler should have two parameters the first one is the value and the second one is the index in array :

```
  <input @input='setFName($event,0)' type='text' name='fn[]' id='fn1' />
    ...
  <input @input='setLName($event,0)' type='text' name='ln[]' ... />
```

and the methods should be like :

```
    methods: {
    setFName(event,index){
        // console.log(event.target.value);
        this.$set(this.fname,index,  event.target.value);
    },
    setLName(event,index){
        // console.log(event.target.value);
        this.$set(this.lname,index,  event.target.value);
    },
    getFullName(i){
  let fullname='';
        if (this.fname[i]!=undefined )
         fullname=this.fname[i];
   if(this.lname[i]!=undefined)
    fullname+=" "+this.lname[i];
    return fullname;

    }
}
```

for more details check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5y2dspk/)

Comment: Boussadjra Brahim: Awesome! :) Greatly appreciated! Earlier, I did pass the id and worked but the index in array was a pain! Upvoted and Accepted.